# How do you pass the path of a batch file into a python script

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I am trying to create a folder tree with a batch file embedded in one of the folders that will be able to create a "run" script for an analysis using a script in a different folder. So, for example, I create a folder tree with a script that puts the batch file into "S:\jobs\work\input files". I want to be able to use that batch file to create journal files in that directory and a sub directory. In order to do this I need to pass the path of the batch file into the python script (which is in S:\scripts)

Here is what I have in the batch file:

```
cls
@echo off
SET /p "fpath"="%cd%"

python S:\Scripts\Create_Journal_File.py %fpath%
pause
```

In the python file, when I do this:

```
file_path = sys.argv[0]
print(file_path)
```

it returns the location of the script file. If I try:

```
file_path = sys.argv[1]
print(file_path)
```

It tells me that there isn't a variable in sys.argv[1]

Thanks!

Comment: The `/P` option is used for input.  The file path of the batch file is `%~dp0`.

Comment: Have you tried running python from the command line first and circumventing the batch file? That way you can diagnose where the problem lies - Python or bat file... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm 0 arg is name of python script itself.

Comment: remove the `echo off` to see, what happens. (I guess, you just press `ENTER` at the `set /p` prompt, which leaves the `%fpath%` variable empty)

Comment: ss64 is invaluable resource for shell scripting.. https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: I should also note that your `SET` command is actually creating a variable named `fpath"` and if you were not using the `/P` option it would also assign a double quote to the variable as well

Comment: There's no need to create a variable whose content is that of another existing variable, `python S:\Scripts\Create_Journal_File.py "%CD%"` would have done it; except you're not after the current working directory, you want the running batch files directory. That can be done by expanding the special metavariable `%0`, thus: `%~dp0`. This expansion will always carry a trailing backslash, if that cannot be accepted or catered for easiliy in your python script, you may use `Set "fpath=%~dp0"` then you can remove its trailing backslash by expanding it to all but the last character, `%fpath:~,-1%`.